# DD-WRT startup script to restart services

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt, bittorrent

I am using DD-WRT v24-sp2 (12/15/14) big - build 25648 on Asus N66U.

I have problem with two services: samba and torrents. With WebUI I set up everything like on the screen. [image: settings]

Issue I have is that during reboot, torrent starts before UNPN & a lot of other services, which I think results in lack of Remote possibility to connect to the Transmission. Even from my local network. If I disable these services and re-enable them, they restart (I have seen logs) and everything is cool until next reboot.

How can this be fixed?
I thought of startup script like this:

```
#!bin/bash
wait 10
killall transmissiond
transmissiond
```

But if I paste it in Administration>Startup Script it does not work.
I have no idea what am I doing wrong :(
Thanks!

Comment: use `sleep` instead of `wait`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the proper script looks like this:

```
sleep 10
killall transmissiond
sleep 5
transmissiond --config-dir /opt/transmission/
```